# How to properly point out the M.Sc. thesis in a Ph.D. application

Tags: phd, application, cv, thesis

Having personally contacted a professor about the possibility of a Ph.D., he asked me to send him a cv and a copy of my M.Sc. in order to evaluate.
Instead, in the online application form of "other" Ph.D. programmes, I have found that I need to include a cv, among the other things, but there is no possibility to attach a copy of the thesis. So, preparing the cv, I thought to imbed an hyperlink to the thesis.

> I would ask you: if it is acceptable, or is counter-productive?

Comment: Most PhD programs ask for ***statement of purpose*** (others ask for Research statement). I believe this is where you should present ,briefly, your research and MSc thesis findings.

Comment: You should distinguish between the search for a PhD supervisor and getting accepted to a PhD program. A potential supervisor is likely to be interested in the details of your thesis. However, when applying to a PhD program, the people going over applications will probably not be interested in the details of your thesis, so you do not need to attach your thesis unless you are asked to. In that case an abstract is more appropriate.

Answer (score 9):

I would advise to add the links, because I don't see what you could possibly lose by doing so instead of not doing so.

You can add links in `LaTeX` using

```
 \href{link.to.thesis}{My MSc thesis title}
```

In my opinion, this is a nice way to link to everything relevant that can not be properly adressed nor otherwise included in your CV. You can for example provide references such as the homepage of your advisor, your department, your other software projects etc. - all just by putting links behind their names.

Answer (score 4):

Fill out the application form as far as possible. You could choose to include in your application a link to an online copy your MSc thesis, as you and others have suggested.

However, **as your potential professor has explicitly asked you for it**, I would send him a copy of your MSc thesis directly, as an email attachment if possible.

Comment: Dear Nicholas, I have already sent him the cv and the thesis as attachments in the response. I was considering also to apply to **other** PhD, and their online application form has a field for a cv but not for a copy of the thesis. So I thought to imbed an hyperlink to the thesis inside the cv.

Comment: I see now. I was confused at the inverted comments around "other".

Answer (score 1):

Send an admissions office the information they ask for. If they give you the option to provide additional information as a text field, then you could list a link to a version of your thesis on Dropbox or on a university web site (or similar) as part of your "additional statement."

However, given the number of applications that a centralized admissions committee might receive, they are probably reluctant to get copies of master's theses and publications—it would be too much extra work to read them all.

Comment: I disagree with the first sentence.  **Send the admissions office the _union_ of the information they ask for and the information they need to make an informed decision.**  If they choose to ignore the additional information, that's their loss.

Comment: @JeffE: The questioner was asking about a case where there isn't an option to upload additional documents.

Comment: There is _always_ an option to type a URL somewhere.